# Is it possible to have smaller packets when uploading images in Alamofire?

Tags: alamofire, alamofire5

my code is something like this:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (data) in 
  // add bunch of large size images 
}
.uploadProgress { progress in
  // print progress
}
.downloadProgress { progress in
  // print progress
}
```

the problem is that uploadProgress takes too long to refresh compared to downloadProgress

is there any way to make uploadProgress update more frequently?

btw: im using alamofire 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Alamofire is at the mercy of the progress callbacks from `URLSession`. You should also know that if your upload is over the threshold, it's first written to disk, which is not reflected in the progress. So you'll see a period of no progress, then the real upload progress, then quick download progress, as the download part is usually just the server acknowledging the upload and is much smaller.

Comment: i see. thank you very much for the insight. didn't really expect the main developer to show up here :)